# Predicting with log transformation in formula

Tags: r

Imagine a simple model

```
fit <- lm(log(mpg) ~ cyl + hp, data = mtcars)
```

to make predictions we have to take exponent

```
exp(predict(fit, newdata = mtcars))
```

Is there any better way to do this then apply it manually? Documentation of `?predict` does not give any helpful hints on this.

I guess, the easiest way would be to extract the transforming function from the formula

```
> formula(fit)
log(mpg) ~ cyl + hp
```

How can I check if any transformation was applied to the left hand side of formula and if there was any transformation, to extract name of the function?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it helps, but you could test it in this manner:
Convert it into character and check if it starts with log/sqrt and the likes:

```
startsWith(as.character((formula(fit))[2]), "log")
```

The answer is true of false:

```
[1] TRUE
```

Maybe this will help you automate your solution?